# One core goes to 100% usage and activate fan on Ubuntu 18.10,

Tags: cpu, fan, 18.10

I recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu 18.10 with [this Notebook](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ROG-GL752VW/), and despite is not a serious problem I noticed that often the fan turn on for ~3 sec. then turn off for ~5 sec. and then turn on again following this pattern.

I've taken a look to system monitor and I noticed that every time it happens, is because one of the cores of the CPU has gone to 100% of usage for few seconds (while the others are almost idle), like it shows the pic below:[image]

I don't get why sometimes one core goes to 100% (for example it happens when I'm just running Firefox with few tabs on the process *Web Content*) and if I can do sometimes to avoid it (at least to the fan, beacuse the continuosly turn on/off it's a bit annoying).

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
It's a little bit difficult to reproduce the problem when I try. Anyway, testing again showed me that sometimes fans activate in the same way also when no CPU reaches 100% of utilization (just lower peaks). Running `ps aux --sort=-pcpu | head` as @Fabby in the comment said, gave me the following :

1. `ollaw     2053 15.1  0.7 443272 126220 tty2    Sl+  nov28  17:00 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -background none -noreset -keeptty -verbose 3`
2. `ollaw     7543 12.0  2.4 2532128 402472 tty2   Sl+  01:03   1:22 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -new-window`
3. `ollaw     7612 10.8  2.5 1978608 413444 tty2   Sl+  01:03   1:13 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 1 -isForBrowser [etc....]`
4. *Almost the same as 3*
5. `ollaw     2234  5.3  1.4 3300616 244520 tty2   Rl+  nov28   5:58 /usr/bin/gnome-shell`

**Other informations:**

- No error in `dmesg` since someone in the answer asked.
- Currently using `nvidia-driver-390` drivers.
- Nvidia is in `intel-mode` (but pretty sure it happens also in `nvidia-mode`).

Comment: Does it happen when other programs except FireFox is running?  It could be one of the tabs in FireFox and closing that one would solve the issue, but we cennot tell you which one...

Comment: It looks like without Firefox happens less frequently but I'm not totally sure. Anyway, it's happened several time in general, with different tab open, so I don't think that's a particular tab.

Comment: But it is only with FireFox? (We need to drill down into where the problem is coming from: is is xorg that has the high CPU or FireFox itself?) use `ps aux --sort=-pcpu | head` on the cli and [edit] your post and provide that output, please...

Comment: If it is only an issue using firefox check `about:support` and check the status of the “multiprocess Windows” option; it should be anbled if not check this: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/05/ubuntu-firefox-multiprocess-enable

Comment: What drivers are loaded for your Nvidia graphics card?

Comment: Currently using `nvidia-driver-390` @MichaelProkopec.
@Fabby it looks like most of the CPU is used by Firefox, but I will now check better and I will update my question with more details.
@db429 on "Multiprocess windows" there's `1/1 Activated Automatically`

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a process needs resources and the process is not capable of using multiple threads concurrently the load will be handled by a single thread. This, in turn, puts load on a single core/thread of the CPU which in turn gets hot leading to an increased fan spin. This increase is especially high if the CPU was in a low power state prior to the resource request because then the temperature change is largest.

You could look either into CPU governors or into fan profiles.

Another approach may be to try to understand exactly under which circumstances which process spikes - it could be a bug or there could be room for improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Use a tool like `top` during the spikes to see which processes are using up your CPU and then kill them (by closing the app or with the `kill` CLI tool).

Or if it's a kernel issue, you would see some errors in `dmesg`, so at least run the command. If there's some text that's red colored or looks like an error that could be the problem.

Comment: thanks for the advice, i will soon add more details to the question and i will include that

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, shutting down the computer, removing the power cord. If this is a laptop, pull the battery. Open the case, removing the CMOS (RTC) battery. Counting to 10 before re-installing the battery. Put all power back into the 'puter.

At the radio frequencies of modern computers, the black arts come into focus. Once and a while, something is not getting to ground, even during power down.

Comment: What do you mean by `At the radio frequencies of modern computers, the black arts come into focus. Once and a while, something is not getting to ground, even during power down.`?

Comment: All electronics operating at common CPU speeds generate micro amounts of RF signals. This is not a health hazard. When literal billions of bits are moving twixt CPU, GPU, Motherboard, DRAM, and hdd, there is a possibility of 1 bit in 10 billion or 100 billion not getting to either one or zero. That is what lead to my suggestion to bring the equipment to absolute ground.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off your nVidia card:

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

Then reboot.

Also it could simply be a glitch with your machine design: [G752VT Left side fan keeps turning on and off!](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?82844-G752VT-Left-side-fan-keeps-turning-on-and-off!)

Comment: I'm currently using intel mode, not sure but I'm pretty sure it happens both with Nvidia and intel mode

Comment: I read that nVidia had a function called something like Mizer that could effect fan turning on/off frequently. My Alienware laptop with GTX 970M has no such problem though...